# Ginzburg Kapranov paper on Koszul duality

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, at.algebraic-topology, operads, koszul-duality

I am studying the article "*Koszul duality for operads*" by Ginzburg and Kapranov, https://arxiv.org/pdf/0709.1228.pdf.

The problem is that this version of the paper contains empty spaces instead of the figures, and I found a bit difficult to read it without them (if it is not clear what the problem is, see for example page 6).

**Question:** Does anyone know where I can find a version of this paper which contains the figures (if it exists)?

Comment: The paper is here (but it is not open access): https://projecteuclid.org/journals/duke-mathematical-journal/volume-76/issue-1/Koszul-duality-for-operads/10.1215/S0012-7094-94-07608-4.full

Comment: Also, the (plain) TeX file is on the arxiv but it just contains vertical space where the figures are supposed to be, so that is not helpful.

Comment: Ask the authors, maybe. Or ask your librarian.

Comment: Thank you @Neil Strickland ! Yes I tried to access the paper on projecteuclid but without success...so do you confirm that there exist a version of the paper without empty spaces?

Comment: I assume that you are the Tomasso Rossi at sissa.it.  I will email you the paper.

Comment: While emailing the paper privately is fine, it would be much better if the authors uploaded the version with figures on the arXiv.  Whatever problems with figures arXiv had at the time, they are obviously gone now.  So I support the suggestion by F. C. to ask the authors.

Comment: @DmitriPavlov This is a paper from 1994 with hand-drawn figures, which were probably incorporated in the main text by the journal rather than the authors.  It is probably quite difficult to put a faithful version on the arxiv.

Comment: @Neil Strickland, I am not the Tommaso Rossi at sissa (it is a quite widespread name here in Italy) but I am a PhD student from Rome (I have not a website right now). I will email you for the paper, thank you very much! 

At the same time I can point out the problem to the authors in order to have an updated version on Arctic,as suggested by the others.

Comment: @NeilStrickland: Yes, that's exactly what I was saying: modern TeX provides standardized tools to include raster images, so the image files previously provided by the authors to the journal could be easily incorporated in the text now by using these tools.  As long as the original images were preserved, there will be no difficulties.